# Let's not engage in [social-manipulation]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

I just encountered the tag [social-manipulation](/questions/tagged/social-manipulation) (currently three questions, no tag wiki). The tag is unclear and seems to portend a rant about what the poster sees as social issues on the site or network.

Can we manipulate this tag out of existence? Questions that relate to social issues could be tagged with more concise tags such as [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse), [spam](/questions/tagged/spam), [offensive](/questions/tagged/offensive), [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct), [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation), [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators), [community](/questions/tagged/community), [company](/questions/tagged/company), [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting), [sock-puppets](/questions/tagged/sock-puppets), or similar tags that describe what the poster is specifically concerned about.

Comment: Lets manipulate this tag out of existence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't participate in [social-manipulation](/questions/tagged/social-manipulation) anymore.

A mixed effort of users manipulated this tag into the garbage bin. Thanks to all who helped out, even though this tag only affected a few questions.

[image: Status-manipulated]

[image: Burninated!]